Man-in-the-middle debugging tools for grpc
Im doing some research on opensource tools available and how it all works for debugging grpc calls. I came across various tools like

grpcurl : just like curl command but for grpc where one can send data and get response and also get details about services and its method declarations and request response body structure
grpcdebug: used to get channels, subchannels, sockets details and health check etc.
grpc-dump: This captures the traffic and dumps a json like tcpdump.

Above all are CLI tools. Some other opensource tools which intercepts http2 traffic which I came across are mitmproxy(interactive, SSL/TLS-capable intercepting proxy for HTTP/1, HTTP/2, and WebSockets) and envoy proxy.
Are there any other opensource (man in the middle tools/proxy tools) tools available for grpc debugging apart from the ones which I have mentioned.
